# .mousemove more effective

Tags: jquery, events

In a web page, I want to show some menu whenever the pointer is near the edge of the `<div>`. I can do it with `.mousemove` , check position and show / hide menu when the pointer is in a specified distance.

As jQuery manual says:

> Keep in mind that the mousemove event is triggered whenever the mouse
>   pointer moves, even for a pixel. This means that hundreds of events
>   can be generated over a very small amount of time.

Is there some neat way to detect if a cursor is in a specified distance from the edge, not involving resource consuming `.mousemove`? I thought about some invisible `<div>` and catching `.mouseenter()` there, but such a div would overlap with other elements and would block other events from those elements.

Answer (score 1):

see the code below which can be used to calculate the distance between a div and mouse pointer

```
(function() {

    var mX, mY, distance,
        $distance = $('#distance span'),
        $element  = $('#element');

    function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        mX = e.pageX;
        mY = e.pageY;
        distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);
        $distance.text(distance);
    });

})();
```

[click here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/calculate-distance-between-mouse-and-element/) for more info

Comment: I think he is trying to avoid the numerous calculations of mousemove

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events they are better than `mousemove` and `mouseenter` combinations.

Comment: Using them I wouldn't be able to detect, when the pointer moves within the main `div` and enters the "activation area", I suppose

Comment: Why not to put more than one div? One div for main content in another one for activation area.

Comment: This might be a bit alternative...but could you possibly convert the div to an image and use an image map/area?  Then you could use Jquery to access these areas and you could define them to be around the edge of the "image" acting as a div

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways i solved this problem is as follows, i basically coded up a producer/consumer solution, where the mousemove event is the producer and a timer is the consumer. Some untested code is below for illustration:

```
var pos = []
var old_pos = []
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    pos = [e.pageX, e.pageY]
    // do something else here?
});
setInterval(function(){
    // do something with the fact that mouse has moved from old_pos to pos;
    old_pos = [pos[0], pos[1]];
}, 100);
```

Personally, i've found that even if i set the interval time to 10 milliseconds, mousemove will still fire 3 times for everytime setInterval fires, so it is saving significant computation, and 10ms is plenty short for fast paced action (1000ms = 1sec, so 10ms = 100 frames per second).